# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am getting this error when I am tring to connect mssql server from linux with PHP.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10007 Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. [10007] (severity 5)
```

Here my Connection Codes:

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

```
$dsn='mssql:host=***;dbname=***;';      
$username='***';
$passwd='***';

try{

$baglanti=new PDO($dsn,$username,$passwd);
$baglanti->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
}catch(PDOException $e){  

    echo 'Error:'.$e->getMessage();
}
```

How Can I solve this issue?

Thanks.